# How to access props value component in test file (Jest and Enzyme)

Tags: react-native, jestjs, enzyme

How to access props value in component in test file (Jest and Enzyme)?
This is my component, I want to access prop value in Pin component in test file (Jest and Enzyme), is it possible?

```
<View style={styles.containerForm}>
  <Text style={styles.textDescriptionGreyFont}>Enter Code</Text>
  <Pin testID={'input_pin'} count={4} value={otp} setCode={(code) => setOtpCode(code)} />
  <View style={styles.containerResendTimer}>
    {renderResend()}
    <Text style={styles.textDescriptionThemaFont}>{renderTimer()}</Text>
  </View>
  <ButtonFull
    testID={'submit_otp'}
    isDisabled={false}
    buttonColor={fullFilled ? color.thema : color.disabledButton}
    onPress={() => submitOtp()}
    title={submitting ? 'Loading ...' : 'Submit'}
  />
</View>
```

Comment: you mean `this.props` ?

Comment: my bad, i want to access prop from pin component in jest and enzyme

Answer (score 0):

You could find the prop value of Pin component like this

```
const wrapper = shallow(<Component .... />);
expect(wrapper.find(Pin).props().testID).toBe('input_pin');
```

Comment: what if i want to check the prop value from pin component?
let say prop value from pin component should be empty string ('')

Comment: What do you mean prop value, which prop value out of the following? I only see 4 props on the component <Pin testID={'input_pin'} count={4} value={otp} setCode={(code) => setOtpCode(code)} />

Comment: If you want to check if it's an empty string then do this expect(wrapper.find(Pin).props().testID).toBe('');

Comment: in component pin, there is a prop count right?
how to check value from prop count component pin?

Comment: if i create like this
expect(appWrapper.find('[id="input_pin"]').props('count')).toBe('')
it will throw error, Method “props” is meant to be run on 1 node. 0 found instead.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution,

```
expect(appWrapper.find('Pin').prop('value')).toBe('')
expect(appWrapper.find('ButtonFull').prop('isDisabled')).toBe(true)
```